# How to drag a Control to a base TableLayoutPanel in the derived Form in a Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, inheritance

I have defined a Base Form.
Note: I am not able to add picture due to an error I am getting from the site 
(Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request ).

So I will try to explain how the form looks like:

The BaseForm contains a TableLayoutPanel with 3 rows and 1 column.
A top cell for the Header, a bottom Cell for the Footer and a middle cell for the content. The middle cell contains a TableLayoutPanel called ContainerTableLayoutPanel.

I have 3 additional forms that inherits from the BaseForm and obviously have the same header and footer.
What I need is to be able to add a different control to each one of the derived form.

I tried to defined the ContainerTableLayoutPanel as protected but I cannot drag any control to it. The controls that were added to the base form are locked in the derived class.

Is there a way to enable dragging controls to a TableLayoutPanel defined in the base form?

Comment: *The `TableLayoutPanel` control does not support visual inheritance in the Windows Forms Designer. A `TableLayoutPanel` control in a derived class appears as "locked" at design time.* Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894861/3110834).

Comment: Forget about `TableLayoutPanel` when using visual inheritance. Use panel or user control.